# the network interface is not shown in the task bar? and how to connect network manager?

Tags: 12.04

The network manager is disabled. Also it doesn't shown in the desktop screen.
Can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Don't leave personally identifiable information on the public internet (yes, this is public).  **:-(**  Please visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, as it is quite different from a forum...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your WiFi hardware switch. It should be on .
And then run the command:

```
/etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

Comment: yup it shows the network manager is connected but it still didn't get IP

Comment: it solved right please vote my answer and marked solved.

Comment: Not getting an IP might be a different problem than the network manager not running. Make sure you have the right settings for DHCP or manual IP. For that, please do as @Pilot6 suggested and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` There are two sides to the network communication, is your router running OK, what are its settings?